# What is a cleaner way of accessing a nested array+hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have the following code, and I feel like there is probably a cleaner way to access the objects that I want:

```
id = job.args.size > 0 && job.args[0]['arguments'].size > 0 ? job.args[0]['arguments'][0] : nil
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what [dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-dig) is for:

```
id = job.args.dig(0, 'arguments', 0)
```

`dig` is defined for Array, Hash, and Struct so it can deal with most kinds of nested structures.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to give advice on how to better organise the code if we can only see one line of it! Dealing with a messy object like this indicates you may have a wider design issue that could improve the code quality. However...

Based on the above, a "happy scenario" is if:

```
job.args == [{"arguments"=>["foo"]}]
```

i.e. An array whose first element is a hash with key `'arguments'`, which maps to a non-empty array. This looks very messy!

However, you can simplify this to:

```
job.args.dig(0, 'arguments', 0)
```

This is applying [`Array#dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-dig) (note: there's also [`Hash#dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-dig)) to chain the method calls and gracefully respond with `nil` if any fail.

This answer assumes you are using **ruby version >= `2.3.0`**, since this is when `dig` was added to the language. If you are running an older version, you could also use [this gem](https://github.com/koic/backport_dig) to back-port the feature.